# How to count items using generate_series() equivalent in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, count, alphabetical

i have a list of users in my Postgresql db and i want to count how many users there are for every letter.

Here is the SQL query:

```
select chr(chars.letter + ascii('A')) as letter,
       count(m.nome)
from generate_series(0, 25) as chars(letter)
left join merchant m on ascii(left(m.nome, 1)) = chars.letter + ascii('A')
group by letter
order by letter asc
```

(thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30084532/2516399))

Here is the result in PHPPGAdmin:

[image]

Now since i migrate to MySQL i need to use the same query but it seems that MySQL doesn't use generate_series(). So, how to get the same result?

Answer (score 1):

So lets assume you have *some* table with at least 26 records in it (maybe `information_schema.columns` perhaps?).

The following will generate all uppercase alphabetical letters:

```
SET @c := 64;

SELECT CAST(CHAR(@c := @c + 1) AS CHAR(1)) AS letter
FROM table_with_at_least_26_rows
LIMIT 26
;
```

To embed the above into your original query, put the `SET @c := 64;` before the query, then replace `generate_series(0, 25) as chars(letter)` with `( SELECT CAST ... LIMIT 26 ) chars`.  Be sure to include the parentheses as it will make the query into a subquery.

SQL Fiddle of the query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6efac/8

Comment: Ehm... the truth is that i cannot embed it :(

Comment: @smartmouse - Can't as in don't know how, or not allowed to?

Comment: I don't know how, i tried several ways but none has worked.

Comment: @smartmouse - Updated answer

Comment: Thank you but now i get this error: `chr does not exist`

Comment: @smartmouse - MySQL uses CHAR() to convert a number to a character, not `CHR()`.  (You probably could have googled that.)

Comment: Sorry about that. Anyway now the query works but the result is wrong: http://pastebin.com/ig5a9hVa
Here is the query i used: http://pastebin.com/LYc4ifCm

Comment: At this point, it may just be quicker/easier to make a table with every alphabetical letter in it.  It'll take all of 60 seconds to make and you'll never need to worry about it again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final solution:

```
SELECT
   LEFT(name, 1) AS first_letter,
   COUNT(*) AS total
FROM users
GROUP BY first_letter
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10150273/2516399)